# JSF 2.2 passthrough in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, html, jsf, glassfish, jsf-2.2

I am trying to use the jsf 2.2 passthrough namespace to pass through certain html5 attributes.

This is what my login.xhtml file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
<h:head></h:head>
h:body>
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="name" a:placeholder="name"></h:inputText>
    <h:inputSecret id="password" a:placeholder="password"></h:inputSecret>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, when editing with the web page editor eclipse is giving me an error in this line

```
xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

The Error says:

```
NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: 
org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
```

I can just ignore that error and the page renders just fine when I deploy the project to glassfish, the placeholder works as expected.

But after that the error disappears (i.e. the line is not yellow anymore) and everytime eclipse tries to validate the file it says:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Processing variables in index.xhtml".
java.lang.AssertionError
```

I have spend hours of googling now and found that there were problems in the early beginnings of jsf 2.2.

I am using the latest versions of the jdk, glassfish and eclipse. I downloaded and reinstalled literally all of it tonight and I still can't fix this. I know that I could ignore it since it's working but I wanna know if I am making a mistake or if it's an eclipse bug.

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

try to use my uploaded JSF frontend project, which is fully configured under JSF2.2 and it will solve your problems. it is a maven project, you can deploy it with eclipse or netbeans, my suggest use NetBeans [JSF2.2 frontend](https://github.com/armdev/jsf-frontend)